# Can't get DataTables responsive working in sails.js + angularjs project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, sails.js

I have imported the necessary `DataTables` css and js file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dependencies/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried to add a js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#userListTable').DataTable({
                responsive: true
        });
    });
```

Not working.

I have tried add the `responsive` in the table html still not working:

```
<div class="dataTable_wrapper" ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    <table class="table display responsive no-wrap table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="userListTable">
    </table>
</div>
```

So how do I get `DataTables` `responsive` to work in sails + Angular.js project?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. I'd suggest using [the bower modules data tables.net provides](https://www.datatables.net/download/bower)
2. When using dataTables with bootstrap styling, the `responsive` usually doesn't work. Try `dt-responsive', because "in Bootstrap the responsive class is used to perform scrolling of a table" - [datatables.net responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/init)